# Save Search in session or database

Tags: usability, user-behavior, design-patterns

I have a table with records. The user can search the table using a Search Dialog. Due to our design constraints, I cannot have the Search criterias as part of a sidebar.

Main Screen:

[image]

Search Dialog (on clicking Search Records button):

[image]

Now, the user may want to apply the search only for the current session or save it permanently in the database. Same for clearing the search. The user may want to clear the search only for the current session or clear the saved search from the database.

The user can save only one such search, and the existing will be overwritten with the new one.

Can the Main Screen and Search Dialog be better designed?

Comment: The records table contains the entire search space? Is this more like a filter than a remote database query?

Comment: @xiota A remote database query is made for every search. The records table does not contain entire search space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try how SSRS reports do on the browser. It has two bars on the top - filter bar and toolbar.

[image]